# NSMutableDictionary, different print from console and code

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsmutabledictionary

I have some questione about NSMutableDictionary. I read that they are only a wrapper around an hashmap, so their use for ordered list is discouraged.

But I have to use it, so the problems began...

I save the result of a Json (after a call to an URL) in a NSMutableDictionary and then I have two different "print":

- if I try to print the dictionary from console with command "po myDictionary" I have an order (the order of the original json)
- if I create a simple "for statement" and print every elements in myDictionary, I have a different order.

How is it possible? Shouldn't they have the same order?

Thank to all!

EDIT: this is a little example of the code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [--{RECEIVED FROM ANOTHER CALL}--];
NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[myDictionary count]];

for(NSString *key in myDictionary) {
    NSLog(@"%@", key);

    NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init]

    /* some operation in the code with object */

    [tmp setObject:object forKey:key];
}
```

After the "for statement" this is what happened:

- if I see all the logs I receive something (for example if myDictionary has the name of the day I have something like "Saturday, Monday, Friday.....")
- if I insert a breakpoint here and try to print something from console with the command "po myDictionary" I have another order, ("sunday, tuesday, monday, ...")

The question is: why?

EDIT 2: I know that there exists a system to have an "OrderedDictionary", but it isn't the question: **I want to understand why I have two different print**, one from the "for statement" and the other from "po command".

Comment: Could you show what is being printed? And how you are actually calling the print?

Comment: Their use for an ordered list is discouraged because they don't guarantee a specific order.

Comment: @Terry: Yeah, I know that their use id discouraged, but this isn't the question.

Comment: @Salcedo: I will edit the question, posting some code

Comment: Which part of not guaranteeing order leads you to wonder why you get a different order in different situations? That's exactly why it doesn't guarantee order.

Comment: ok, I know. But if I have an hashmap and if I want to see all elements, the order follow a simple alghoritm. If I insert the same values and try to access them I have the same order ever. And this is what happen: if I insert the same value I have the same order, if I insert another the order changes.

But if I have an hashmap -> I access it with those different commands -> the orders are different -> those command don't do the same.

My question isn't "why they are unordered" but "Why the result of the order are different"

Comment: Okay, marked down; this question is not satisfactorily answerable because the OP isn't really asking anything. He's just complaining "I did two different things and got two different results" which is a tautology.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree: I have a NSMutableDictionary and with PO and with a for statement I got two different result.
I think is "one thing -> two result", so I wanted to know why. And someone answered, so a difference between PO and for exists ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `po <object>` command in gdb prints the output of `[<object> description]`. `[NSDictionary description]` sorts its output by key. This is [documented behavior](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If your JSON is sorted by key (which it sounds like it is), then you can just sort by key again to ensure a reliable order.

Note that if your JSON is using an object (a collection of key/value pairs) to represent ordered data, it is in violation of the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627).

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

The correct encoding is an array of single-key objects such as:

```
[ { "firstKey": "value" }, { "secondKey": "value" } ]
```

But if you can use sorted keys to define order, that's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks very much, it is exactly what Iwant to know: PO print [<object> description].
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NS(Mutable)Dictionaries aren't ordered, period. (It's not just discouraged.) There's no guarantee that even if you got the "original order" that `po` provides, it'd stay that way from app launch to app launch, or from OS version to OS version, or from hardware to hardware. Don't do that.

Maybe you want to use something like http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html?

Comment: thanks but I can't use it... I receive the Dictionary "as it".

Comment: @MarcoPace I hate to say it, but in that case, there's not much you can do other than complain to whoever is giving you the dictionary -- no one should give you a dictionary and then expect you to be able to read order off of it. In your circumstances, it sounds like the people to talk to are is the api provider who gives you the json.

Comment: thanks for help, I think the best thing to do it's to change the data I get

Answer (score 2):

Hashmap do not have key or value order，and not promise any order. If you need same order, you can use array of key-value pair, or use http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html .

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer an ordered dictionary: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Okay, you've now modified your original question. You're now asking:

> I know that there exists a system to have an "OrderedDictionary", but it isn't the question: I want to understand why I have two different print, one from the "for statement" and the other from "po command".

That's because they are two completely different ways of accessing the data. The for statement walks the keys one by one in some order. The po command calls the dictionary's `description` method, which clearly does not consist of a for statement enumerating the keys like yours. I don't understand why you find this puzzling.

Comment: I knew it, but I can't use: I receive the Dictionary "as it", I can't modify the way I create it... And if I try to loop through my dictionary it is already unordered.

Comment: Yes, but you create the ordered dictionary from the original dictionary and now you have an ordered dictionary pointing to exactly the same data. Thus, walking the data happens in a consistent order. Or do what Rob suggested and enumerate the sorted keys to walk the data. You are not making clear why these are not good solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I modified a bit the original text because, after a second reading, I had to admit that the question was wrongly asked. Thanks for help