# How to make for loop iterate in the same order as NSLog(@"%@", arrData)

Tags: objective-c

I executed the following code `NSLog(@"%@", arrData);` and the output in the debugger was expected like so:

```
    "0." =     {
"first_name"="John"
    };

    "1." =     {
"first_name"="Florence"
    };

    "2." =     {
"first_name"="Melinda"
    };
    "3." =     {
"first_name"="Zack"
    };
```

I then executed this code:

```
for (NSDictionary *book in arrData)
{
        NSLog(@"%@ %@" , book, [[arrData objectForKey:book]  objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
}
```

And the output was like so:

```
2. Melinda
0. John
3. Zack
1. Florence
```

How do I make the for loop print the results in the same order as ? `NSLog(@"%@", arrData);`

Comment: You don't.  Entries in an NSDictionary are unordered, and may not even be returned in the same order two times in a row.  If you want them ordered, put the data in an array and sort it the way you want.  (Hint: Retrieve the list of keys, sort them the way you want, then work through that list to retrieve the index values.)

Comment: Here is your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360100/nsmutabledictionary-different-print-from-console-and-code

Comment: What Hot Licks said. You can't enumerate an unordered collection and expect to operate on the items in a specific order. @HotLicks you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things are going on here.

First let's understand what `%@` means in NSLog. Many iOS/Cocoa developers incorrectly believe `%@` is associated with NSString, it's not. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265):

> Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by `descriptionWithLocale:`if available, or description otherwise. Also works with `CFTypeRef` objects, returning the result of the `CFCopyDescription` function.

So, `%@` takes any Objective-C or CFTypeRef object. Since you are using a `NSDictionary`, `%@` will print the output of description or `descriptionWithLocale:(id)locale`. So what does that do? Again, from Apple's documentation:

> If each key in the dictionary is an NSString object, the entries are listed in ascending order by key, otherwise the order in which the entries are listed is undefined.

When using the for-in loop, aka Fast-Enumeration, the order of the objects is undefined, so that is why the output of the loop is not in order.  If you wanted to print the contents of an NSDictionary in order, you'll have to emulate the behavior of the description method.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3583109/257533) stackoverflow post:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    [sortedValues addObject: [dict objectForKey: key]];
}
```

I hope this clears things up.